# How to show the message age in Wanderlust's summary buffer?

Tags: email, wanderlust

I tried to customize Wanderlust's summary buffer by changing `wl-summary-line-format`. I would like to see the age of a message in the summary buffer. But I can not find any abbreviation for the age of a message.

In Gnus it was possible to define a `gnus-user-format-function-x`, which could be referenced in the `gnus-summary-line-format`. But I can not find anything similar in Wanderlust.

How to show the age of a message in the summary buffer?

Comment: Describe variable `wl-summary-line-format` and that gives you a list of what's available.  If it's not there, then you would need to implement the feature or do without.  My preference is to use:  `(setq wl-summary-line-format "%T%P [%5(%c %S%) %] %M/%D/%Y (%W) %h:%m %t%[%25(%c %f%) %] [%75(%c %s%)] %n")`

Comment: @lawlist Is there somewhere the age in it?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really know what `age` is -- I rely on the dates a message was sent, and I sort automatically with the newest messages at the top of the buffer.  The word `age` is nowhere to be found within the source file `wl-vars.el`  If you haven't done so already, type:  `M-x describe-variable RET wl-summary-line-format RET` and read the doc-string of available options.

Comment: age is the time from now till the time the message has been send. For example "one hour ago", "yesterday", "last week", "two years ago".

Comment: Ah . . Thank you.  Someone would need to implement that feature for you, or you would need to write it yourself -- it does not presently exist.

Comment: Yes in in Gnus it is possible by the use of the gnus-user-format-function-x. But how to do it in Wanderlust?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to write the `wl-summary-line-age` function yourself, but the way to add a new summary line format string, e.g. `%a` is to use:

```
(defun wl-summary-line-age ()
  ... some magic with the wl-datevec variable (see wl-summary-line-year, etc.)

(setq wl-summary-line-format-spec-alist
      (put-alist '?a
         '((wl-summary-line-age))
         wl-summary-line-format-spec-alist))
```